# PHP / CodeIgniter: Nginx throws 404 and ignores class and method

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I'm using LEMP (Linux Nginx MySQL PHP).

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

This is my controllers/Pages.php

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home') {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_500();
        }

        show_500();
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

In config/routes.php, this is the default controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

Now, when I go to

```
http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php
```

I get a screen which says:

```
Welcome to CodeIgniter!
The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.
If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:

    application/views/welcome_message.php

The corresponding controller for this page is found at:

    application/controllers/Welcome.php

If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the User Guide.
```

But, when I go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/pages
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/pages/view
```

I get a 404 error. I'm not raising a 404 error anywhere in my Pages class, so I'm assuming my Pages class is not even being called. Any idea why I'm getting a 404 error / why my Pages class in not being called?

Edit:

```
http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/welcome
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/welcome/index
```

return 404 errors as well. It's weird because in Welcome.php it says:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *

     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
```

Edit 2: It is Nginx throwing a 404. I think it might have to do with my Nginx configuration, which is this:

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

I'm thinking maybe the issue is in this part:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
```

Maybe because Nginx first tries to serve the following URL as a file and directory

```
http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/welcome/index
```

and because the URL above is neither a file nor directory, Nginx is throwing a 404?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in unix system, capitalization can result this issue. check it. it might work. try http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/Pages  (capital P as controller's name is Page not page).

Its strange but same issue happened with me and i was able to troubleshoot and solve it this way. i had to rename controllers name using small letters.

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it did not work either. Nginx is still throwing a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home') {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        //show_500(); comment this line

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

> Note: Page not found Error is `404` not `500`

Comment: hm tried it, I'm still having the same issue (Nginx is returning a 404). I purposely made it "show_500();" because I wanted to see if that line of code is even being executed or not, and it isn't so from my understanding the problem is occurring even before the Pages class is called.

Comment: check your `Pages` controller file name

Comment: the file name is Pages.php and it is in the controllers folder. I tried renaming it to pages.php and this doesn't work either.

Comment: remove this `if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }`

Comment: just tried to remove that as well, it still gives the same error. Note: I'm also getting the same error when I try to visit http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/welcome as well.

Comment: comment this `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

Comment: just commented that out, still receiving the same error :/

Comment: Nginx is the web server I'm using (similar to Apache). This person faced a similar issue as the one I'm facing right now: http://serverfault.com/questions/695521/codeigniter-in-subdirectory-on-nginx-404 so I'm going to try posting this question on ServerFault and see if they have a solution.